# docker containers application servers and application

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container

Experts.

I am newbie to Docker. Started exploring the docker and its tools and successfully created the docker setup [using toolbox in win 7] and created a websphere-liberty image and deployed my spring boot application as war [needed as war as per my company requirement]. Also linked to eclipse, so I can develop and run from eclipse and the application runs in docker container. I am in the process of creating an app image [war] for my application.

Now my question.

Architecturally what is the good approach and need help on how to do.

1. Create one container with Websphere-liberty image and manually add the application image in that.
2. Create two containers, one having Websphere-liberty and another with image of my application and make the application run on the server.

or any other good approaches ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should inherit from this image (https://hub.docker.com/_/websphere-liberty/) and COPY the war to the new image.

So if by "manually" you mean by using a Dockerfile, then yes solution number 1, otherwise just do what I explained to you.

Note: Do not add the war-file by using a volume like explained on the websphere-liberty image page... This is bad practice in my opinion and might only be suitable for dev, if suitable at all...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By Manually, yeah I meant Dockerfile. something like mentioned in docker hub for liberty. Is there a way to automate that with maven build like using spotify ? any pointers will be usefull thanks